# Change detection between two binary images

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, change-detection

Is there a scientifically-valid to use raster calculator to subtract two binary images (0, 1) to get the difference between Pre- and Post flood events?

In pseudo-code:

```
Difference "change detection" = Post-event flood event (1,0) - Pre-event flood event (1,0)
```

I tried it and got difference map, but I want to make sure it is valid method.

There are 4 possible cases:

1. recorded flood events in the post- and pre-images and the result would be (1-1=0), 2
2. flood event in the post-image and no flood in the pre-image, and the result would be (1-0=1),
3. non-flood in the post-image and flood in the pre-image, and the result would be (0-1=-1),
4. non-flood in both post-and pre-images, so the result would be (0-0=0).

The main concern around the interpretation of the third case.

Comment: What do you mean by OK? Are you asking if it will throw errors? Or are you asking if the results will be valid? If the former: try it yourself and find out. If the latter, create a small test case (say 5 pixels by 5 pixels) and verify the results by hand.

Comment: You are right, I mean is it valid or not. Actually I tried it and got difference map but I want to make sure if it is valid method. I mean there shold be 4 possible cases:

Comment: What is your concern with the third case?

Comment: How it could be interpreted, particularly there is no water bodies or lakes in the area

Comment: Use combine, to cover all 4 cases. Perhaps assign 0 to dry land, if not already.

Comment: Alternatively reclassify them into 1,2 and 4,8 and find sum.

Comment: Yes 0 is dry land and 1 is flood. Could you please explain more the reclassification idea

Comment: well, 1) no data set is perfect 2) sometimes rivers move 3) there's no way anyone could possibly provide any insight to data that you haven't given us access to.

Comment: Thank you FelixlP and Paul for your time and help. The area is an arid area in Iraq.

Answer (score 1):

This is what combined raster table looks like:
[image]

So Value of 1 corresponds to dry land before and after; 2 - was dry become flooded etc.

Alternatively one can use fact that sum of any two numbers in range (0,1,2,4,8..) gives unique combination. Those who used paper tapes for coding will understand this real quick:) So you can do:

```
arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa('("AFTER"+1)*2', "C:/SCRATCH/SCRATCH.gdb/Reclass")
arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa('"BEFORE" + "Reclass"', "C:/SCRATCH/SCRATCH.gdb/fromReclass")
```

Reclass raster will store values of 2 - dry and 4 - wet.
Output of sum:

[image]

Where value of 2 (0+2) is dry/dry, 5 (1+4) is wet/wet.